# To Communicate with a device over bluetooth which profile I have to use

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, eaaccessory, bluetooth-profile

I want to send/receive data to/from iOS app with an accessory over bluetooth. So which one bluetooth profile I have to use to from "MAP, PAN, HID", in accessory and how to use that in iOS app???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3647 for Bluetooth 2 profiles that are supported by Apple. I would recommend using Bluetooth 4 (LE), but I have no idea how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sebastian you are right. You can use BT "classic" profiles such as "MAP, PAN, HID", but you would need to enroll MFI program:  [mfi program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/), and your accessory would need to include a MFI chip.

You can also use BTLE. It depends on the data you need to share. No MFI chip is needed. You have some info about iOS BTLE here: [Core Bluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

iOS didn't implemented protocols that allow to communicate to other non-iOS devices.

There will not be any chance for implementing this sooner. Because Apple primarily focusing on the security.

Comment: I want to develop a accessory that communicate vice-versa with iOS app over bluetooth. So which bluetooth profile I have to use in accessory?